# What sort of oil/lube is "Shimano Internal Hub Maintenance Oil"?

Tags: internally-geared-hub

[image]

[https://www.amazon.com/Shimano-Internal-Hub-Maintenance-Oil/dp/B00O58QCQY](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00O58QCQY)

I know what it is for. But what is it composed of?

Comment: Mainly it's simply oil with the right "weight" to be optimal in a geared hub.  It also contains a bit of dye, presumably to help identify leaks.

Comment: If you're asking whether it's worth 63 bucks, probably not.  But you'd have to figure out what the equivalent weight gear oil would be.

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure for Shimano but my Rohloff Hub used SAE 80 weight gear oil.  I can't imagine shimano has magic that isn't covered by the SAE standard.

Comment: I use many litres of ep80/90 in my old landrover, and it has a particularly distinctive smell.

Comment: Here is a link to a blog post of a Shimano IGH rebuild that uses automobile automatic transmission fluid... http://www.14degrees.org/shimano-alfine-8-speed-internal-gear-hub-oil-bath/

Comment: Just because you could use ATF doesn't mean you should.  I'm positive that using the wrong oil (okay, not using the branded right oil) will void the remaining warranty.

Comment: This answer misses the important point that Rohloff oil comes with a detergent wash to be applied and drained out as a first step, where the Shimano dunk procdure has nothing like that. It's been speculated that Shimano dunk oil has a detergent mixed in.

Comment: Yes. But what exactly is the genuine Shimano nexus oil? 
I know you can use trans-fluid. The closest thing I thought it could be was...

https://www.trademe.co.nz/a/motors/boats-marine/parts-accessories/other/listing/3837284309?gclid=Cj0KCQjwnvOaBhDTARIsAJf8eVPDu9l_sjDyHRF_XyDaEbm2ctElpgcbBL896tQ9UyxwuPHTF6VceQcaAhM8EALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds

as it's the same color blue and it's application is a salty watery environment.

Answer (score -1):

You don't have to use shimano original oil.
I changed my Nexus 8 from grease to oil lubricant and the result is really fantastic. I'll never use grease again (of course grease is used for the ball rings).
I took oil with the same specifications as mentioned in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tJvGnrDBTNA).
I paid 14 Euros per liter.

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles.  The question was asking specifically about the _composition_ of the Shimano-branded oil.  Do you have any information that's relevant to the question?